# What is the right way to check for one or more postbacks in a Django template?

Tags: python, django, django-templates

First, is the right way to check for a postback in a Django template:

```
{% if request.POST %}
    <div id="elementThatShouldBeInTheDOMIfPostBack">
    </div>
{% endif %}
```

And second, is there an elegant way to determine what N is if it's the Nth postback, i.e., due to validation errors?

Comment: Could you explain what you're trying to accomplish? Because the template will never know if you're issuing a GET or a POST method.

Comment: Question edited. I only want an element to appear on the page if it's a postback.

Comment: Then in your `views.py` send a template variable to check something with.

Answer (score 1):

Generally it is a bad practice to include any logic in to your django templates. Templates in django are used only to represent things that has been calculated/processed by your view function. You should do it in your view function eg. using sessions:

```
#----views.py------

from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import MyForm

def someview(request):
    form = MyForm()

    if not 'postbacks' in request.session:
        request.sesson['postbacks'] = {}
    if request.path not in request.sesson['postbacks']:
        request.sesson['postbacks'][request.path] = 1

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)

        if not form.is_valid():
            request.sesson['postbacks'][request.path] += 1
        else:
            request.sesson['postbacks'][request.path] = 1


    return render(request,
                  'myapp/tamplate.html',
                  {'form': form, 
                   'postback': request.sesson['postbacks'][request.path]})
```

Then on your template simply use :

```
{{ postback }}
```

Cheers! Do not forget to up-vote this answer if you feel it was helpful ;)

Comment: I edited the original question. I agree with you logic, but I need the logic on the template to control whether the page includes an HTML element.

Comment: What do you mean: "whether the page includes an HTML element" ?

Comment: See the original question. That div should only appear in the DOM if it's a postback, in other words, a second attempt.

Comment: Well once you have postback context variable you can do it like this: {% if postback > 1 %}<div id="elementThatShouldBeInTheDOMIfPostBack</div>{% endif %}